# Use async-native-tls with a custom CA

Tags: ssl, rust, openssl

I'm attempting to connect to a transparent Burp proxy using `async-native-tls`. The way the transparent Burp proxy works is that it generates a new TLS cert based on the SNI parameter of incoming TLS connections on the fly. These TLS certs it generates are all signed by a Burp CA.

When I run my code, I get an error from OpenSSL complaining about a self-signed certificate in the chain. That's totally expected. In fact, all TLS certificate chains have a self-signed certificate in the path -- the CA! I believe I've correctly configured the Burp CA certificate as an alternative to the system CA.

Below are the relevant snippets.

```
use async_native_tls::{Certificate, TlsConnector};
use http_client::hyper::HyperClient;
use http_client::{hyper, Config, HttpClient, Request};
use std::error::Error;
use std::sync::Arc;

let mut tls_builder = native_tls::TlsConnector::builder();
tls_builder
  // This is important, as it's how Burp knows which certificate to present
  .use_sni(true)
  // This is important, as it indicates that Burp's CA should be trusted
  .add_root_certificate(Certificate::from_pem(
    std::fs::read("/tmp/ca.pem")?.as_slice(),
  )?)
  // These should not be required, but I've turned them on in despairation
  .danger_accept_invalid_hostnames(true)
  .danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
  .disable_built_in_roots(true)
  .max_protocol_version(None)
  .min_protocol_version(None);

let burp_proxy_tls = TlsConnector::from(tls_builder);
let burp_proxy_config = Config::default().set_tls_config(Some(Arc::new(burp_proxy_tls)));
let mut http_client = HyperClient::new();
http_client.set_config(burp_proxy_config)?;
let mut request = Request::get("https://127.0.0.1:8000/...");
request.append_header("Cookie", "...");
// Not strictly needed since it's also in SNI
request.append_header("Host", "...");
let mut response = http_client.send(request).await?;
```

When I connect via `s_client`, everything verifies OK:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8000 \
 -servername www......com \
 -CAfile /tmp/ca.pem \
 </dev/null
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = PortSwigger, ST = PortSwigger, L = PortSwigger, O = PortSwigger, OU = PortSwigger CA, CN = PortSwigger CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = PortSwigger, O = PortSwigger, OU = PortSwigger CA, CN = www......com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = PortSwigger, O = PortSwigger, OU = PortSwigger CA, CN = www........com
   i:C = PortSwigger, ST = PortSwigger, L = PortSwigger, O = PortSwigger, OU = PortSwigger CA, CN = PortSwigger CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jan 10 02:29:14 2023 GMT; NotAfter: Jan 10 02:29:14 2024 GMT
 1 s:C = PortSwigger, ST = PortSwigger, L = PortSwigger, O = PortSwigger, OU = PortSwigger CA, CN = PortSwigger CA
   i:C = PortSwigger, ST = PortSwigger, L = PortSwigger, O = PortSwigger, OU = PortSwigger CA, CN = PortSwigger CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jan 24 00:53:54 2014 GMT; NotAfter: Jan 24 00:53:54 2033 GMT
...
subject=C = PortSwigger, O = PortSwigger, OU = PortSwigger CA, CN = www.......com
issuer=C = PortSwigger, ST = PortSwigger, L = PortSwigger, O = PortSwigger, OU = PortSwigger CA, CN = PortSwigger CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2521 bytes and written 403 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

But then the program fails:

```
$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.15s
     Running `target/debug/xxxxxx`

Error: error trying to connect: error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889: (self-signed certificate in certificate chain)

Caused by:
    0: error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889: (self-signed certificate in certificate chain)
    1: error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889:
```

Comment: Your problem is that you haven't specified the domain name (i.e. you haven't specified the equivalent of the OpenSSL `-servername` option.)

Comment: @virchau13  I thought that setting the Host header would be sufficient since it can't get the hostname from the URL. I can't see any other obvious way to do it from the API docs.

Comment: Lame, it looks like `http-client` will ONLY look at the URL for the hostname and nowhere else. https://github.com/http-rs/http-client/blob/14dd1bb460d695735bd4d5ec63f78419bf02f8c7/src/h1/mod.rs#L131

Comment: Hyper-tls also only looks at the URI to decide what to use when sending the SNI field. https://github.com/hyperium/hyper-tls/blob/74044e32b5eb6cdc8a70978a1f584dc7b0748932/src/client.rs#L128

Comment: If you can find a way to send a HTTP request over a raw socket, you can use https://docs.rs/native-tls/latest/native_tls/struct.TlsConnector.html#method.connect to specify a SNI.

Comment: Also, what exactly is `HyperClient` and `http_client.set_config()`? I can't find any docs mentioning either of those functions.

Comment: I've added imports to help clarify, but `async-native-tls` is a wrapper over one of several HTTP clients (hyper, h1, curl, etc) and over one of several TLS implementations (openssl, schannel, etc). It gives you escape hatches to directly configure the underlying HTTP client / TLS implementation before using it's high-level API to make requests. Unfortunately, those escape hatches don't seem to be sufficient for what I'm trying to do here or the underlying libraries just aren't geared for it

Comment: The `TlsConnector::connect` method you linked above is what is called in the `tls.connect(&host, tcp).await?;` on line 138 of the hyper-tls link I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never did figure out if this was possible with the `async-native-tls` library. I wasn't tied to that library so I switched to `isahc` since it was backed by CURL and I know I can get that to do what I want.

I did have to switch my burp proxy to port 443 because `isahc` doesn't support `--connect-to` yet, but I can work with that.

```
let http_client = HttpClient::builder()
        .dns_resolve(ResolveMap::new().add("www.......com", 443, [127, 0, 0, 1]))
        .ssl_ca_certificate(CaCertificate::file("/tmp/ca.pem"))
        .ssl_options(SslOption::DANGER_ACCEPT_INVALID_CERTS)
        .automatic_decompression(true)
        .build()?;

    let request = Request::get("https://www.......com/....")
        .header("Cookie", cookies)
        .body(())?;
    let mut response = http_client.send(request)?;
```